# javascript variable variable names and global scope (pinesnotify)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I'm using pines notify (somewhat irrelevant to my issue, I imagine) to create notifications on the change event of a drop down list. On the server side, the change is saved to a database, then when the save is complete - I wish to remove the notification (or do something else depending on the result).

The problem is in creating the notification object in a way that I can later reference it (to remove it).

My intended solution would obtain the id of the dropdownlist, prepend 'pn' to it and use that as the variable name, much like

```
var pnid = 'pn' + $('#mydropdown').attr('id');
notifications[pnid] = createNotification();
```

In the codebehind I can create javascript code knowing what the notification object will be called.  However I'm struggling with my 'notifications' object.. I've tried this[notifications], window[notifications] etc. to no avail (ie I cannot later reference this object to interact with it) . I'm creating that object outside of any functions like so

```
var notifications = {};
```

Am I going about this the completely wrong way?

Comment: If `notifications` is declared as a global you can simply reference it as `notifications`, you don't need to say `window.notifications` or other variations thereon. (`window[notifications]` won't work because that looks for a property of the `window` object with a property name equal to whatever `notifications` evaluates to.)

Comment: Thanks @nnnnnn - apologies I didn't spot this comment here - pretty sure you hit the nail on the head for me though :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this line before reaching `notifications` object.

```
window.notifications = window.notifications || {};
```

This will help you create the object if it is undefined and it will also prevent you from overriding it if it already exists.

*Note : I assume you have to use this object as a global variable.*

Comment: +1, Clever! But is the problem here with overriding the previously declared variable?

Comment: You don't have to declare it outside the function somewhere like OP does. If this line works more than once, you have to check if it already exists.

Comment: Thanks for the proposed solution.. however I'm not sure the reason for the code. Perhaps that's what Adnan's suggesting - I declare it once.. then wish to reference/manipulate the object in multiple areas of the page.

Comment: Well if you declare it outside of a function with var keyword that makes it a global variable and it should work fine.You also have to make sure it's declared before anyone tries to reach it. My solution would work in a function scope and only create the global variable when it's needed. Not much of a difference.

Comment: Right, that makes sense now.. I'll accept your answer as it cleared up some of my confusion - however I think I was just mixing up notifications(text) with notifications('text') - figured that out after lots of tweaking! It was the 'should work fine' which made me have a closer look. Thanks again :)